# Firestore cloud function querying for database: Document does not exist

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write an http cloud function that triggers a query to search for items whose price is more than 100 bucks, but it always returns me empty document or the document does not exist.

Rules are set to skip verification for now so that  I do not need to authenticate.

Am I missing something here?

I am new to firestore/firebase.

[Collection/Document image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sox78.png)

```
export const queryForData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

db.collection('Inventories').where('price','>=',100).get()

    .then(snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.exists){
            const data = snapshot.data();
            response.send(data);
        }else{
            response.send("No docs found!")
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

This gives me "No docs found!"

Comment: hey @Doug i was watching your videos.. help me :(

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your question to include some sort of description of the collection or documents that you're trying to query.  As this question stands, I can't tell if you're querying the correct things.

Comment: Does the picture help? I was getting frusturated here, before your comment ^_^ love your videos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The snapshot you have in your code is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), and does not have an exists property or data() method. It looks like you're getting it confused with a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot), which *does* have an exists property and data() method.

So you would want to do something like this:

```
.then(snapshot => {
    if (!snapshot.empty) {
        for (let i = 0; i < snapshot.size; i++) {
            const data = snapshot.docs[i].data();
            response.send(data);
        }
    } else response.send('No docs found!')
}
```